# Does Double.Parse("NaN") parse correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, double, nan

Does the C# `Double` parse "NaN" correctly, ie. does `Double.Parse("NaN").ToString() == "NaN"`?

Comment: LinqPad returns `True` for `Double.Parse("NaN").ToString() == "NaN"` for me

Comment: Note that "NAN" will generate a parse exception. I ran into that when sending a double as string from a C++ program to a .NET program.

Comment: @participant a NaN is NEVER == to a NaN. Never! The correct test should read `float.isNaN(Double.Parse("NaN")) == true`

Comment: @ПетърПетров Why parse a double and test for float.IsNaN?

Comment: @participant my copy-pasta mistake :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var d = Double.Parse("NaN");
Console.WriteLine(d); // prints "NaN"
```

I'm running under the en-US locale. As Joey notes, be careful around this. I got the same results when I specified the invariant culture (as one often should in these circumstances):

```
var d = Double.Parse("NaN", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // prints "NaN"
```

Comment: The `WriteLine` would print `n. def.` on my system. If you're passing explicit cultures, you have to do so on printing values as well.

Comment: @Joey: Honestly, that would not have occurred to me - I suppose I assumed "NaN" was a cross-locale invariant, kinda like the symbols used to identify elements on the periodic table. Changed; thanks.

Comment: Check `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NaNSymbol`. If you have a `NumberFormatInfo` that's not read-only (for example, you can `Clone` to get one) you can even assign your own favorite string to `NaNSymbol`.

Answer (score 7):

Try it:

```
PS> $ic = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
PS> [double]::parse('NaN', $ic).ToString($ic)
NaN
```

However, parsing and output of this string is locale-dependent, so either make sure you're always passing a culture or don't make too many assumptions about the format.

Comment: Yeah, I was bitten by the locale issue with my first try ;)

Comment: PowerShell, yes. A nice way of quickly trying out .NET stuff without firing up Visual Studio with ConsoleApplication2345.